# FileZilla transferring MP3 and MP4 files reduced in size

Tags: ftp, file-transfer, filezilla

I am transferring files from a Linux SFTP to FTP on Windows. And I am checking my windows file system and I see that there is larger free space than on linux, so I started checking each folder individually and found out that MP4 and MP3 files are not transferred in their full size, for example MP3 file that is around 120 MB after downloading it, it would show up as an MP3 40 MB in size.

Can anyone explain why is it happening and how to avoid it ? 
I have tried to transfer all 2 TB drive by using 1-simultaneous-transfer mode and the same problem occurs again - some files are not in their full size.

[image]

EDIT: I read that Binary or ASCII file transfer mode might be the problem.
Just tried to 'Overwrite if different size' and it downloaded the correct size.

Comment: If redownload with the same settings fixed the problem, it cannot be due to ascii mode. Also ascii mode cannot reduce the size by more than 50%. And hardly by more than 1% for a compressed files like MPx.

Comment: Is it SFTP or FTP transfer? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl It's SFTP transfer.
I re-downloaded everything that was with a different size and still there are some files that are not the same size.